# get specific xelement child value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

```
<information items ="2">
    <table id="31"> </table>
    <profile code="5">
        <name language="ro"> Spania </name>
        <name language="gb"> Spain </name>
        <name language="pl"> Hiszpania </name>
    </profile>
</information>
```

I do want to take the value of the element `<name>` having its attribute `language = "gb"`

I tried something like:

```
string country = xdoc.Descendants("information").Elements("profile").Elements("name")./*???Value???*?
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx):

With [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string country = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("/information/profile/name[@language='gb']").Value;
```

With [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string country = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/information/profile/name[@language='gb']").InnerText;
```

Keep in mind that you also need the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace.

Comment: I have: XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader); and  reader = XmlReader.Create(Url);
                reader.MoveToContent();

Comment: then use the first example. It's for the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace

Comment: for the 2nd example, xdoc should be an XmlNode, not a XDocument?

Comment: But in my scenaria: xdoc is a XDocument, not an XmlNode

Comment: [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) supports the method I mentioned

Comment: The specified method is not working for me: unrecognized method. Even if I added this: using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: do you have `System.Xml.Linq.dll` referenced? or are you using `XDocument` from an other library? Which .Net Framwork version are you using?

Comment: the method exists at least since v3.5

Comment: I added this: using System.Xml.XPath; and now it works

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm new in .net programming and I learn every day new aspects... In the near future, I'll assume I will ask for the help again...

Comment: always a pleasure to help. that what SO is for